# In the Japanese dub, is there any parallel to Baobao's use of Sichuanese?

Tags: japanese-language, hitori-no-shita

Near the beginning of the second episode of *Hitori no Shita: The Outcast*, Baobao reads out details about her new identity as a student supposedly from Taiwan to Zhang Chulan. In the Chinese version of the episode that I saw, Baobao's Mandarin Chinese pronunciation in this specific segment sounds very non-standard. (Elsewhere, her pronunciation sounds normal.) Zhang Chulan in fact remarks that she is speaking 四川话 (i.e. Sichuanese).

Is there any mirroring of this use of a regional language variant in the Japanese dub? If I remember correctly, the subtitles on Crunchyroll, which broadcast the Japanese dub, only have Zhang Chulan indicate that Baobao is lying, but which makes me suspect not. However, as I do not know Japanese, I would like for someone to perhaps confirm this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I watched the first three episodes of *Hitori no Shita*, and can confirm that Baobao speaks plain old standard Japanese (*hyoujungo*), with not a hint of any regional lect. In episode 2, Chulan indeed only states that the details she's reading out are obvious lies.

(It came as a surprise when I learned that she spoke a non-standard variety in the Chinese audio version. Kinda strange that they wouldn't similarly pick a non-standard variety of Japanese for the Japanese version.)

Comment: For what it's worth, I dropped the series after two or three episodes, but my impression was that her pronunciation outside of that specific section was more normal.

Comment: @Maroon Ah, I see. That makes sense - I'm guessing this is funny in Chinese because you wouldn't expect a person from Taiwan to speak Sichuanese? (But there's no stereotype for what a "Japanese-speaker from Taiwan" sounds like, so the joke wouldn't translate.)